# Trivial subset selection with array in R

Tags: arrays, r

I have an 6*3*3 dimensional array:

```
a<-array(data=rep(1:5,10),dim=c(6,3,3)
```

I have another vector with 3 numbers:

```
b<-1:3
```

I would like to do the following selection:

Select from the first column of `a` those values that that have b in their second column. 
I would like to use b as an index for the third dimension of `a`. i.e. the first value of `b` should be searched in `a[,,1]` the second value of `b` in `a[,,2]` and the third value in `a[,,3]`

The original array looks like this:

> a

```
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    2    3    4
[3,]    3    4    5
[4,]    4    5    1
[5,]    5    1    2
[6,]    1    2    3

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    5    1
[2,]    5    1    2
[3,]    1    2    3
[4,]    2    3    4
[5,]    3    4    5
[6,]    4    5    1

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    3    4
[2,]    3    4    5
[3,]    4    5    1
[4,]    5    1    2
[5,]    1    2    3
[6,]    2    3    4
```

after the selection this is what I would like to get:

```
 , , 1

     [,1] 
[5,]    5 


, , 2

     [,1] 
[3,]    1  


, , 3

     [,1] 
[1,]    2 
[6,]    2
```

Comment: Side note: R does not save the original row/column numbers, so you'd get `[1,]    5` instead of `[5,]    5`, for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
lapply(seq_along(b), function(i) a[a[, 2, i] == b[i], 1, i, drop = FALSE])
```

Note that the output is a list of one-column matrices. I don't think you can get away without a list because the number of matches for each `b[i]` may differ. Also, you might want to remove `drop = FALSE` so the output will just be a list of vectors.